# Records inserting in another table when inserting in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm just tired by finding out an issue from last more then 5 hours.

I have a table named `tblDomains`. When I insert a simple record into that table, it inserts a record into another table `tblSites` also. I don't know how its happening.

There was only one trigger created on table `tblDomains`. I dropped the trigger and still its inserting a row in another table.

**Below is the simple query I'm using to insert records in table `tblDomains`**

```
INSERT INTO tblDomains(DomainName, CompanyName, Logo, 
                       Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, Phone,  Fax,
                       tblConfigs_ID, Enabled, tblPricingPlans_ID, ExpireDate, AllowExport, 
                       InactiveDate, tblDomainTypes_ID, ActiveLicenses, AllowPPC, Debitor)   
VALUES ('Dname2', 'Cname2', '', 'ad1', 'ad2', 'ct', 'st', '12345678', '21212121211',  
        '32132132131', 4, '1', 1, null, 0, null, 1, 5, 0, 0);
```

Can anyone help that how I can track the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is issue but you can do one this. If possible change the name of tblSites or insert a such values in the tblDomains so that it will throw error while inserting tblSites. I think from error message you may get some clue who is inserting data into  tblSites  :)